# Ruby update 187 to 193 performance hit with Savon 2 SOAP Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, soap-client, savon

We have recently attempted an upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 from ruby 1.8.7. It's overdue to say the least. However, while the rest of the entire application seems much quicker, the part of the application that uses SOAP has taken a dramatic hit. On our local development copy on the largest loading page has an increased page load time of 7 seconds! We are using Savon 2.2.0 / Rails 3.1.12 and I was wondering if anyone else has seen this kind of behavior and what they did about it?

I have read in a couple of places that Wasabi gem could be the culprit. After updating to the development version of 4.0.0 with implied performance enhancements I hit quite a few errors. I can see how to fix these now, but it will mean re-writing quite a substantial amount of code. Does anyone know if this Wasabi update is a sure thing? I see that Savon 3 will be using it...

I am trying to avoid re-writing everything with a different SOAP client, plus I like Savon, so any help with this would be very appreciated! However if many have moved away from Savon because of this which SOAP Client would you recommend.